# How to get youtube channel earning using youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I have YouTube channel, How to get YouTube earning using YouTube analytic API. I am not YouTube "Content Management System" partner.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can only approximate earning with your number of view day by day.

Comment: Is there any sample code or API to get it.

Comment: get what ? the view day by day ? in the YouTube Analytics but it require an authentication by the owner.

Comment: I want to get earning of my channel not view analytic

Comment: like i say, you can only approximate earning with your own method.